# I need help converting an Apex Page to Lightning Component

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I am brand new to both Apex and Salesforce and am trying to convert a Salesforce Page to a Lightning Component. I have provided the original code, and where I have gotten to below for reference. I believe I am missing something for getting the current Case's AccountID. I may be way off but I am here for help and to learn.
The component should list all child domain (urls) of the parent account in a table. Image shown below of what the completed work should be.
Right now the component does display and no problems or errors in the debugger, but now child domains are displaying. Not even the table label "Domain Name."
[Children Domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6rJt.png)

```
UPDATED CONTROLLER CLASS
public class CollectionCaseDomainsController {
    public List<Domain__c> domains {get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void queryDomains(Domain__C domains, Id AccountId) {
        if (AccountId == null) { return; }

        //query all the children accounts (if any)
        Set<Id> allAccountIds = new Set<Id>{AccountId};
        Boolean done = false;
        Set<Id> currentLevel = new Set<Id>{AccountId};
        Integer count = 0;
        while(!done) {
            List<Account> children = [ SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Parent.Id IN :currentLevel ];
            count++;
            currentLevel = new Set<Id>();
            for (Account child : children) {
                currentLevel.add(child.Id);
                allAccountIds.add(child.Id);
            }

            //added in a count, to prevent this getting stuck in an infinate loop
            if (currentLevel.size() == 0 || count > 9) {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        //query the assets
        List<Asset> assets = [ SELECT Domain__c FROM Asset WHERE AccountId IN :allAccountIds ];

        Set<Id> domainIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Asset a : assets) {
            domainIds.add(a.Domain__c);
        }

        domains = [ SELECT Name FROM Domain__c WHERE Id IN :domainIds ];
    }
}
```

```
LIGHTNING COMPONENT
<aura:component controller="CollectionCaseDomainsController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="AccountId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="Domains" type="Domain__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="childDomains"
                      recordId="{!v.AccountId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.Domains}"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      />

    <lightning:accordion activeSectionName="Domains">

        <lightning:accordionSection name="Domains" label="Domains">

            <lightning:datatable data="{ !v.Domains }" columns="{ !v.Columns }" keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>

        </lightning:accordionSection>

    </lightning:accordion>
</aura:component>
```

```
LIGHTNING CONTROLLER
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.Columns", [
            {label:"Domain Name", fieldName:"Domain__c", type:"url"}
        ]);

        var action = component.get("c.queryDomains");

        action.setParams({
            AccountId: component.get("v.AccountId")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            component.set("v.Domains", data.getReturnValue());
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

```
ORIGINAL PAGE
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CollectionCaseDomainsController"> 
    <apex:slds />

    <!-- Lightning -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d' || $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4t' }">
        <div class="slds-scope">
            <!-- Domains Found -->
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(domains)) && domains.size > 0}">
                <table role="grid" class="slds-table slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover slds-scrollable_none">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                            <th aria-label="Domain Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-text-title_caps" scope="col">Domain Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <apex:repeat var="domain" value="{!domains}">
                            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ domain.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank">{!domain.Name}</a>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <!-- No Domains -->
            <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!(ISNULL(domains)) || domains.size == 0}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <!-- Classic -->
    <apex:form rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme3' }">                 
        <apex:pageblock id="DomainList"> 
            <br/> 
            <!-- Domains Found -->
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!domains}" var="domain" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(domains)) && domains.size > 0}">                
                <apex:column headerValue="Domain Name">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!domain.id}" target="_blank">{!domain.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <!-- No Domains -->
            <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!(ISNULL(domains)) || domains.size == 0}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel> 
        </apex:pageblock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

```
ORIGINAL CONTROLLER
public class CollectionCaseDomainsController {
    public List<Domain__c> domains {get;set;}
    public Case current_case;

    public CollectionCaseDomainsController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) stdController.addFields(new List<String>{'AccountId'});
        this.current_case = (Case) stdController.getRecord();
        queryDomains();
    }

    public void queryDomains() {
        if (this.current_case.AccountId == null) { return; }

        //query all the children accounts (if any)
        Set<Id> allAccountIds = new Set<Id>{this.current_case.AccountId};
        Boolean done = false;
        Set<Id> currentLevel = new Set<Id>{this.current_case.AccountId};
        Integer count = 0;
        while(!done) {
            List<Account> children = [ SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Parent.Id IN :currentLevel ];
            count++;
            currentLevel = new Set<Id>();
            for (Account child : children) {
                currentLevel.add(child.Id);
                allAccountIds.add(child.Id);
            }

            //added in a count, to prevent this getting stuck in an infinate loop
            if (currentLevel.size() == 0 || count > 9) {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        //query the assets
        List<Asset> assets = [ SELECT Domain__c FROM Asset WHERE AccountId IN :allAccountIds ];

        Set<Id> domainIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Asset a : assets) {
            domainIds.add(a.Domain__c);
        }

        this.domains = [ SELECT Name FROM Domain__c WHERE Id IN :domainIds ];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a screenshot of what it looks like. No one has the same objects as you so it's hard to depict what this looks like. Also when you say you have some of it done, what is left? What exactly are you stuck on? Be mindful this community is for support, not outsourcing work.

Comment: Of course. This is homework for training that I was given. These components have been converted in the past already, so they are use cases for homework for an actual completed app we are "re-building" individually.